# Restrict User To User Only One Control Per Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a `User Control`. Now I want to restrict the user that he could only use one 
`User Control` per Form.

Assume that my custom control is Text Box. In this case User can only use one Text Box per Form.

Comment: There's nothing that a user can do to add controls to a form.  Only a programmer can do that.  Of course there is nothing you could or should do to stop a programmer from creating the program the way he wants.  If you try anyway then your UC will quickly end up in the bit bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Enterevent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-ud/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
         this.TxtBox.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.TxtBox_Enter);
         private void TxtBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
         { 
              //disable all other textboxes
              foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is TextBox)
                    {
                        c.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to restrict you user from having more than one instance of your control on single form use following trick to restrict

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.UserControl1_Load);
        }
        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ParentForm.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().Count() > 1)
            {
                //form already has a controler throw error
                throw new System.Exception("you can have only one instance of me on a single form");
                this.Enabled = false;
                this.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That would be the one and ONLY time I used such a control.  Next stop, the circular file.